# Accoring to the manual, numpy.squeeze() returns ndarray, but in some conditon, it doesn't, why?

Tags: python, numpy

The official manula: [numpy.squeeze](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html)

> **Returns**: squeezed : ndarray
>
> > The input array, but with all or a subset of the dimensions of length 1 removed. This is always a itself or a view into a.

But when I run the code below, it seems that numpy.squeeze doesn't returns a ndarray

```
import numpy as np
cost = np.float64(1.1)
print(type(np.squeeze(cost)))
```

The result is `<class 'numpy.float64'>`, not `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`.

I am confused, why? Is the function's documentation incomplete or is it a bug?

Comment: If you send it a `float` why *would* it return an array and not a `float`?

Comment: The manual says: "This is always a itself or a view into a.". In your case, it has returned a.

Comment: We don't normally creat `np.float` objects directly.  We may get one by indexing an array.

Comment: I think it is a bug, because ```np.squeeze(np.float(1.1))``` returns ndarray. Feel free to report an issue at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues

Comment: @tstanisl I don't think it is a bug. `np.float` is just an alias for plain python float.Unlike genuine numpy sclar types---which are not 0D arrays, but behave pretty much like those---it doesn't play nice with code that expects an array, so it makes sense to make a 0D array here.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, you are right. It looks that scalar types have squeeze() method that behaves different from what np.squeeze() expects. Maybe the doc should be updated from "Returns: squeezed : ndarray" to "Returns: squeezed : ndarray or scalar"

Comment: `np.squeeze` delegates to the object's `squeeze` method.  Thus `np.matrix` squeeze returns a `np.matrix`, etc.  `np.float64(3).squeeze()` does like wise.  `np.float(3).squeeze()` raises an error.  In many, but not all, ways `np.float64(3)` is like a `np.array(3, np.float64)`, a 0d array (it has an `item()`, `shape`, `dtype`, can be indexed with `[()]`, etc).